# What is the difference between siteUrl and baseUrl?

Tags: craft3, siteurl

What is the difference between `siteUrl` and `baseUrl` in Craft 3? Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look into Craft you'll see this

```
 /**
 * @var string|string[] The base URL to the site(s). If set, it will take precedence over the Base URL settings in Settings → Sites → [Site Name].
 *
 * This can be set to a string, which will override the primary site’s base URL only, or an array with site handles used as the keys.
 *
 * The URL(s) must begin with either `http://`, `https://`, or `//` (protocol-relative).
 */
public $siteUrl
```

So the `baseUrl` is what you insert in your site settings, the `siteUrl` can overwrite these values from your config

The `Site.php` (model) has a this function as well

```
/**
 * Overrides the base URL while keeping track of the original one.
 *
 * @param string $baseUrl
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function overrideBaseUrl(string $baseUrl)
{
    $this->originalBaseUrl = (string)$this->baseUrl;
    $this->baseUrl = rtrim($baseUrl, '/').'/';
}
```

which is called in the Site service

```
$site->overrideBaseUrl($generalConfig->siteUrl);
```